# Escaping from the escaping hell

Tags: listings

Given the following MWE, where the argument for the `code` function contains an underscore:

```
\documentclass [11pt,oneside,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{hello_world.c}
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  // return 0;
}
\end{filecontents*}


\makeatletter
\def\code{\@ifnextchar[{\@with}{\@without}}
\def\@with[#1]#2{
}
\def\@without#1{
  \section{#1}
  \lstinputlisting[]{#1}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\code{hello_world.c}
\end{document}
```

The same argument `#1` is used in two different functions: `section`, which requires the underscore to be escaped, and `lstinputlisting`, which requires the underscore *not* to be escaped.

If the user escapes the filename, compilation fails because of `section`. If the user doesn't escape the filename, `listings` cannot find the filename.

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. You might think that this is better but we cannot reproduce what you mean by just copy/pasting your code and compiling. Instead we have to make our own each time which is tedious. Why don't you give a full one as I did in your previous question?

Comment: Because I didn't know about `makeatletter` and `makeatother`, which I just saw in your answer. Putting everything in a single file without those commands was causing a `Use of \@ doesn't match its definition.` error, which is why I didn't use a single file. I was doing my best to ease your job. Sorry about that.

Comment: Note that there are many ways to define commands with optional arguments that are *much* more robust than using `\@ifnextchar`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please try to make your MWE self contained (as in this answer) it really helps when answering.

You can use the eTeX primitive `\detokenize` to make `_` safe and then `T1` font encoding so a `_` character gets printed as an underscore:

```
\documentclass [11pt,oneside,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{listings}

\def\code{\@ifnextchar[{\@with}{\@without}}%
\def\@with[#1]#2{%
}
\def\@without#1{%
  \section{\protect\detokenize{#1}}%
  \lstinputlisting[]{#1}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\code{hello_world.c}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, only drawback is that the underscore is not rendered correctly in the TOC (it minimizes the "w").

Comment: Sorry a `\protect` was missing. Also I added some `%` at the ends of lines (unrelated to your problem but uncommented line ends could produce unwanted white space in the output)

Answer (score 14):

There are several packages that takes care of typesetting file names, e.g. url, path. The following example uses package url. I have assumed that the optional argument of `\code` has the purpose to pass options to the lstinputlisting command. In this case the hacking
with `\@ifnextchar` is not necessary.

```
\documentclass [11pt,oneside,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{makerobust}

% Define \file that typeset a file name using the url package
% that also takes care of hyphenation issues, ...
\newcommand*{\file}{}% to get an error if \file is already defined
\DeclareUrlCommand{\file}{\urlstyle{sf}}
% Different styles are available, e.g.:
% sf: sans serif font (\sffamily)
% rm: roman font (\rmfamily)
% tt: typewriter font (\ttfamily)
\MakeRobustCommand{\file}
% as robust command \file do not need \protect

\newcommand*{\code}[2][]{%
  \section{\file{#2}}%
  \lstinputlisting[{#1}]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\code{hello_world.c}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have `\makeatother` but I don't see a `\makeatletter`, is that right?

Comment: @PatrickT: Thanks for noticing. It's probably a left-over from a previous version and I have removed it now.