# File name with underscore as figure caption

Tags: packages, optional-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Escaping from the escaping hell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64929/escaping-from-the-escaping-hell)

I did scour the internet for solution but I found no satisfactory answer for this problem.

I have a bash script that searches my folder for .pdf images and creates a latex file with several `includegraphics` commands with the file names as the figure caption.

However, my file names have underscores and this is unavoidable. When I run `pdflatex` on the below latex file, I do get a pdf file with all my figures as required but the captions are all italicized or subscripted.

Any ideas on how I might avoid this (**how should I allow underscores in figure captions?**):

### Latex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eps2pdf}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[super,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{grrfile}
\newcommand{\hilight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}


% \usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}

\date{07/31/12}

\begin{document}

\clearpage


\begin{figure}[h] 
\begin{center} 
\centering 
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{/home/dnaneet/Research/Dissertation/APS2012/G=0.0/L_2lambda_max_1wl_zg_2m.pdf} 
\caption{L_2lambda_max_1wl_zg_2m.pdf} 
\label{fig:fig1} 
\end{center} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Edit:

Using the underscore package helped only partially:

- The caption is fine now and the file name is displayed.
- Since the file name has underscore, that messed up the path and hence the figures aren't displayed anymore.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Right, but the `underscore` package only "\_ in text mode (i.e., \textunderscore) prints an underscore"...

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I loaded the `underscore` package. No change in the situaiton. In fact it is worse as the figures are no longer displayed in the eventual pdf file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not really. Not a duplicate.

Comment: @DNA Ah, I didn't saw the path also contained underscores; I'll delete my comments.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Your comment was useful! `:)` however, like you noticed , the path is screwed up now! `:P`

Comment: @DNA the referenced question was asking about underscore in section and table of contents, yours about caption and list of figures, but the issues (and fix) are identical

Comment: @DNA: As David mentioned, you can use `\caption{\detokenize{L_2lambda_max_1wl_zg_2m.pdf}}` together with the `T1` font encoding (`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`).

Comment: @Werner This seemed to work. Perhaps you should use this as the answer! Thank you

Comment: @DNA: Since the linked question specifically references sectional units (and is therefore similar, but not exactly a duplicate IMO), I've added an answer to this question based on my comments.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `\detokenize{L_2lambda_max_1wl_zg_2m.pdf}` removes the math interpretation of `_` and adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` allows for the correct printing of `_` inside the caption. For completeness, the following setup should work:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
%...

\begin{figure}[h] 
  \centering 
  \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{/home/dnaneet/Research/Dissertation/APS2012/G=0.0/L_2lambda_max_1wl_zg_2m.pdf} 
  \caption{\detokenize{L_2lambda_max_1wl_zg_2m.pdf} }
  \label{fig:fig1} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

For preserving the underscores within the LoF, use `\caption{\protect\detokenize{..}}`.

Comment: `\detokenize{}` works quite well, but it stops if I want to generate the `listoffigures`. How could I get around it? Right now, the work around is to escape each `_` (`\_`).

Comment: @AlbertNetymk: Use `\protect\detokenize{..}`. It prohibits expansion of `\detokenize` which happens typically within moving arguments as they are written to (auxiliary) files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. `\protect` does the trick and it compiles fine. Unfortunately, in `listoffigues`, the underscore is missing. In other words, `\protect\detokinize{first_name}` becomes `first name` (Not exactly one ` `, but you could try and see what it is really.

Comment: @AlbertNetymk: I am not getting that output at all (see the [output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1qVHV.png) using a very minimal document). Underscores are preserved in the LoF. Perhaps, if this is a pressing concern, ask a [follow-up question](http://goo.gl/vWjuk).